# Cognos 10 Framework manager crashes with 'BMTUI2' error. 'An error is at the origin of this program malfunction. Close the program'

Tags: cognos-10

After adding new data source from Cognos production (content manager administration) and testing succeeded, I added the new data source in framework manager as mentioned in your doc and as my other datasources that are available.

Upon testing the connection or using the new metadata model or if i created a new project, i receive the following error and Framework manager crashes with the following error.
BMTUI2 stopped working!
'An error is at the origin of this program malfunction. Close the program'

I tried to restart the server, using a complete shutdown, but nothing.

I verified the tnsname file on oracle client to make sure that the connection details are available .

I googled the error, and nothing related was found.
I posted a question on IBM forum and no reply in one week !

I verified all other datasource configurations and they are all similar.

N.B: The new datasource is an oracle datasource as my other datasources, and is located on the same database server.

Please help in resolving or understanding what this error means, or what can be done to resolve it.

I am using Framework manager v. 10.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found, hope it helps

> https://www.cognoise.com/index.php?topic=4202.0

- delete your csk, encryptkeypair and signkeypair folders.
- Open your cognos configuration, save it again
- Try to open cognos

or

> control panel --> system --> advanced system settings --> performance
> --> settings --> data execution prevention

- turn on the Data Execution Prevention for essential windows programs and services only
  OR
- turn on DEP for all programs and services except those u select (here add bmt.exe)

Cognos 10 runs on a "windows server 2008 R2 standard" machine and works fine now

Comment: I saw this article, and did test your second opinion, but didn't work. I was trying not to manipulate any file that has any configuration information, but seems that I do not have a choice else than testing the first one.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Framework Manager on your local windows machine?

Comment: It is a production environment, i cannot re-install it like this, actually i found a restriction settings that was set to 1 database, i set it up to 5 just to test, but nothing has changed. I have to restart the service and check if that solves the issue.